# Unexpected reserve word 'await'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const loadUsers = async () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    showLoader();

    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");
    let userData = (await response.json()).data;

    setAllUsers(userData);
    setUsers(userData);

    hideLoader();

  }, 3000);
};
```

Comment: `await` is inside `setTimeout`'s function. This one should me marked as async.

Comment: await must be used on async functions, look at `setTimeout(() => {`, you must use `setTimeout(async () => {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `async` and `await`, the `innermost` function that contains the `await` statement is required to have the `async` keyword.

> Try this.

```js
const loadUsers = () => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    showLoader();

    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");
    let userData = (await response.json()).data;

    setAllUsers(userData);
    setUsers(userData);

    hideLoader();

  }, 3000);
};
```

Comment: _"Try this"_ is not a helpful answer... What have you changed? And why?

Comment: To expand on why this works. If you want to use aysnc await, the innermost function that contains the await statement is required to have the `async` keyword.  In the question's example the outermost function had it instead of the function inside the `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2):

I feel having a `setTimeout` function within an `async` function is just a nasty implementation.

A cleaner way to do this would be to just define your logic that needs to be executed in a **isolated function and call that specific function after a specified time**. Also, the error you get is because you tried calling `await` within a **non** `async` function. For your code to work you need to set the inner function passed to `setTimeout` as `async`

###### Cleaner approach:

```js
const loadUsers = async () => {
   showLoader();

    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");
    let userData = (await response.json()).data;

    setAllUsers(userData);
    setUsers(userData);

    hideLoader();

};

setTimeout(loadUsers, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark method as async to solve the error, but this can lead to unexpected behavior because you aren't waiting for the timeout itself, and you can't because the return value of setTimeout is a "timeoutID" and not a Promise.

To solve the problem you can return a Promise like this:

```
const loadUsers = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => { // return a Promise to handle setTimeout usage
        setTimeout(async () => { // mark this function as async
            showLoader();
    
            const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");
            let userData = (await response.json()).data;
    
            setAllUsers(userData);
            setUsers(userData);
    
            hideLoader();
            resolve(); // the returned promise
        }, 3000);
    });
};
```